# HTML + CSS How can I make a fixed background with scrolling content

Tags: html, css

This may have been asked before, but I am doing an html project and I need to have a fixed background with everything else scrolling. All the solutions I have come by involve javascript of Jquery and I would like to not use either but if it is the only way I might have to. (keep in mind i have very little coding experience with javascript or Jquery) 
One example of a fixed background with scrolling content like i intend is shown here. 
http://www.teamunify.com/Home.jsp?team=ohossc 
-thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can, potentially, use:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

In concert with whatever other CSS you're using to style your content.

References:

- [`background-attachment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment).

Answer (score 1):

My friend, that is ultra easy, at least check the internet.

```
<div id="background-image">
   <div class="your_content">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#background-image {position: fixed;}
```

No need for Jquery

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Taken from here:

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Replace the url to the relative or absolute path of your image.